# Is there a way to enable blending and depth at the same time in Metal

Tags: ios, textures, alphablending, metal, depth-buffer

I have a metal view that displays some textured quads. The textures are loaded from PNGs so are premultiplied. Some of the textures have transparent pixels.

When I enable blending and draw in the right order, the transparency works and you can see quads beneath other quads through the transparent parts of the textures. However, I'm having to calculate the right draw order by sorting which is expensive and slowing down my rendering a lot.

When I've tried to use depth stencils and draw in any order, I can get the order working correctly using z position, but then the blending stops working. The transparent parts of the texture reveal the background color of the metal scene rather than the quad below.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get this working and could someone provide some example code?

The other option I see is to try and do the sorting on the GPU, which would be fine as the GPU frame time is significantly smaller than the CPU frame time. However, I'm also not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: You've run into one of the great annoyances of computer graphics. Alpha compositing is an [order-dependent operation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting). As you note, sorting on the CPU gets expensive. Sorting on the GPU can be done, but you'll need to express it as a radix sort or other GPU-friendly algorithm. Other options include alpha testing (if your alpha values are all either 0 or 1 and you can handle losing antialiasing on your edges) or various [order-independent transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency) techniques.

Comment: @warrenm Thanks again for commenting Warren. As it happens, my textures do have an alpha of either 0 or 1 and in fact the game I'm building is pixel-graphics so I deliberately don't want anti-aliasing. Sounds like alpha testing could be a good fit! Do you have any examples of how I can implement this in metal?

Also, I do want to make my quads semi-transparent sometimes. But that's not related to the texture data. I assume that is still possible with alpha-testing?

Comment: Right, alpha test and alpha blending are not mutually exclusive. You'll still run into the need to sort from back-to-front if you want proper compositing, but perhaps less work will be required if only certain sprites are translucent. To achieve alpha test in Metal, you just call the built-in `discard_fragment` function in your fragment shader when you determine it should be transparent. It will not be written to the color buffer, and more importantly for your purposes, it will not affect the depth buffer either.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://metalbyexample.com/translucency-and-transparency/), it explains how to do alpha testing and blending in Metal. This site in general is a one of the few great resources for learning Metal.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha blending is an order-dependent transparency technique. This means that the (semi-)transparent objects cannot be rendered in any arbitrary order as is the case for (more expensive) order-independent transparency techniques.

- Make sure your transparent 2D objects (e.g., circle, rectangle, etc.) have different depth values. (This way you can define the draw ordering yourself. Otherwise the draw ordering depends on the implementation of the sorting algorithm and the initial ordering before sorting.)
- Sort these 2D objects based on their depth value from back to front.
- Draw the 2D objects from back to front (painter's algorithm) using alpha blending. (Of course, your 2D objects need an alpha value < 1 to actually see some blending.)

And you need to setup pipelineStateDescriptor correctly:

```
    // To have depth buffer.
    pipelineStateDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .depth32Float

    // To use transparency.
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Hope this helps. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042114/1223728)